# Generate Successive Number Pairs - Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have some code that takes a given list of pairs of numbers and solves for chains of 7. However, it takes an obnoxious amount of time to solve for even one (well, i haven't solved for 1 yet and it has been a large amount of time). I was wondering if there was a better/more efficient way of coding this.

Here's what I did, with out the numbers in the list "L". (the list looks like such: `L= [[1,2],[2,3],...]`)

```
length(L,LEN),

interval(N1,1,LEN),
interval(N2,1,LEN),
interval(N3,1,LEN),
interval(N4,1,LEN),
interval(N5,1,LEN),
interval(N6,1,LEN),
interval(N7,1,LEN),

nth1(N1,L,A),
nth1(N2,L,B),
nth1(N3,L,C),
nth1(N4,L,D),
nth1(N5,L,E),
nth1(N6,L,F),
nth1(N7,L,G),

nth1(2,A,A2),
nth1(1,B,B1),
A2 = B1,

nth1(2,B,B2),
nth1(1,C,C1),
B2 = C1,

nth1(2,C,C2),
nth1(1,D,D1),
C2 = D1,

nth1(2,D,D2),
nth1(1,E,E1),
D2 = E1,

nth1(2,E,E2),
nth1(1,F,F1),
E2 = F1,

nth1(2,F,F2),
nth1(1,G,G1),
F2 = G1,

nth1(2,G,G2),
nth1(1,A,A1),
G2 = A1,

R = (A,B,C,D,E,F,G).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, you can write this shorter as

```erlang
use_module(library(clpfd)).

q(L,R) :- 
  [A,B,C,D,E,F,G] ins 1 .. 7,
  R = [[A,B],[B,C],[C,D],[D,E],[E,F],[F,G],[G,A]],
  permutation(L, R),
  label([A,B,C,D,E,F,G]).
```

Example:

> 3 ?- q([[1,7],[2,3],[5,4],[3,1],[7,6],[6,5],[4,2]],X). 
>   X = [[1, 7], [7, 6], [6, 5], [5, 4], [4, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1]] **;** 
>   X = [[2, 3], [3, 1], [1, 7], [7, 6], [6, 5], [5, 4], [4, 2]] **;** 
>   X = [[5, 4], [4, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [1, 7], [7, 6], [6, 5]] **;** 
>   X = [[3, 1], [1, 7], [7, 6], [6, 5], [5, 4], [4, 2], [2, 3]] **;** 
>   X = [[7, 6], [6, 5], [5, 4], [4, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [1, 7]] **;** 
>   X = [[6, 5], [5, 4], [4, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [1, 7], [7, 6]] **;** 
>   X = [[4, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [1, 7], [7, 6], [6, 5], [5, 4]] **;** 
>   **false.**

But your question is really unclear.

*update:* We can create the kind of lists we use above, of any length, with

```erlang
vars(N, Vars):-
    length(Vars, N).

pairs(Vars, N, Pairs):-   % assuming vars(N, Vars)
    N #> 0,
    append(Vars,[A],[A|B]),   % |B| = N
    maplist( pair, Vars, B, Pairs).

pair( A, B, [A,B]).
```

Such that `q/2` can be generalized as

```erlang
gen_q(L,R) :- 
  length( L, N),
  vars( N, Vars),
  Vars ins 1 .. N,
  pairs( Vars, N, R),
  permutation(L, R),
  label(Vars).
```

But computational feasibility of this for larger inputs is another matter entirely. The brute force of `permutation/2` may have to be replaced with something more specific.

Also, the `N` results produced comprise a clear pattern; there's no need to re-enter the search to produce them all after the first one is found.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but your code only works if there is 7 pairs in the list. My data set is ~150 pairs

Comment: no problem, just that when no answer is accepted it signals that the issue is still unresolved... :)